# I want to get a way to highlight code using the python Tkinter Text control

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to implement a code highlighting function, but I don't know how to use this `tk.Text` 。 (not necessarily python, of course)

I hope to get a highlighted function `f (x, y, z, a)` whose function is to highlight it into the a color from row x, column y to column z. Then I also hope that every time the user enters in the text control, I can receive a message and call the another function `t (x, y)` to update the highlighted content. I hope to get this kind of writing.
In addition, I don't want to use a third-party library to solve this problem. My reference code is as follows. You can modify my code to answer this question.

Reference code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('600x600')
window.configure(bg='white')

content = tk.Text(window, relief='solid', font=('Consolas', 12))
content.pack()
content.place(x=15, y=15, width=570, height=535)

window.mainloop()
```

My English is not very well. I use machine to translate my text, so it may contain some low-level errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use search function to search the first index of you word and then use this "%s+%sc"%(starting_index(that you will find with the help of search function),length of your word)

if you don't want to download any external module then I suggest you to use **idlelib** this is a build in module

you can try this:-

```
import tkinter as tk
def highight_function(code_list):
    for i in code_list:
        content.tag_remove(i,"1.0",tk.END)
        starting_index = 1.0
        while True:
            pattern = r"\m{}\M".format(i)
            starting_index = content.search(pattern,starting_index,regexp=True,stopindex=tk.END)
            if not starting_index:
                break
            last_index = "%s+%sc"%(starting_index,len(i))
            content.tag_add(i,starting_index,last_index)
            starting_index = last_index
        content.tag_configure(i,foreground=code_list[i])
    window.after(1000,lambda :highight_function(code_list))


window = tk.Tk()
code_list = {"from":"cyan","as":"cyan","import":"cyan"}
window.geometry('600x600')
window.configure(bg='white')

content = tk.Text(window, relief='solid', font=('Consolas', 12))
content.pack()
content.place(x=15, y=15, width=570, height=535)
window.after(1000,lambda :highight_function(code_list))
window.mainloop()
```